# Mat Radio button value is not changing after form submission

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular2-directives

I am using a translate service by changing language english to french and changing the label of the radio button but when i submit the form, the form value of radio remains as it is..

I used a custom-dir directive based on click event I'm setting the attribute value of mat radio button and its getting changed (translated) to "man", but when I submit form orignal value="male"is getting submitted.

change

//custom directive[image: My custom directive[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIQPG.jpg)

Comment: Im using a directive:

@HostListener('click') onclick() {
    let value = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    this.render.setElementAttribute(value, 'ng-reflect-value', 'true');
    this.render.setElementAttribute(value, 'value', 'true');
  }

Comment: Please post full working example code.

Comment: Please check the pictures @G.Tranter

Comment: Please post code not images of code. Images don't allow copy and pasting to try things out. You should always provide *working* examples preferably StackBlitz.

Comment: Okay. I was trying to copy paste the working code but I couldn't use the format properly. I will try to post the stack blitz soon.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't try to manipulate the internal attributes of the Angular Renderer, instead use the data-binding and some pipes to update your values. Please refer to the `@ngx-translate` project, and there you can see that you can subscribe to lang changes on the  `TranslateService`, so you can update your value listening that change.

Sadly I don't have time right now to draft some code, but I hope that Google has some examples or language selectors.
Happy coding!